# Java Error whilst attempting to run a web-client

Tags: java

I'm having some problems while trying to open a web-client for a game that I play. I get this error and I don't know what to do. Help would be appreciated. If you need any more information please let me know and I will do the best I can to get it.

```
load: class client.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.class
```

Comment: Do you have access to the source code/is this something you're developing or are you trying to play a game somebody else wrote and you're getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are running your web client like this:

```
$ java client.class
```

Try running this instead:

```
$ java client
```

Comment: To be brutally honest, I don't know where I would change that. I am extremely new to Java.

Comment: I am trying to run a RuneScape Private server, and whenever I try and join it, I get this error message.